# How to insert image in mysql table, then displayed on the screen?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following problem.
I need to print the pictures (the pictures are in mysql).
My mysql code is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Images (
     ID INT, NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     IMAGE BLOB,
     PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

And I inserted as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Images (IMAGE) VALUES (LOAD_FILE ('/Desktop/node/img/1.jpeg'));
```

Now I want those images to be displayed in my code (I write it in node.js).
When I write the following code, it prints only the IDs.

```
router.get ("/", (req, res, next) => {
     db.query ("SELECT * FROM Images", (err, row) => {
         if (err) {
             throw err:
         }
         else {
             res.render ("index", {data: row})
         }
     });
});
```

What can I do to get those pictures displayed on the screen?

Comment: Don't? Store your image in a static asset location (be that a local dir, an AWS bucket, or whaever else works) and store the _metadata_ (e.g. filesize, dimensions, where it can be found so you link to it in a template, etc.) in your database.

Comment: How to do it in C# is written here: [Writing a File to the Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-blob-writing.html) / [Reading a BLOB from the Database to a File on Disk](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-blob-reading.html).  Hopefully this can help you to get this done in node.js.

Comment: Use `SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE` and save the image to disk. Then process this image file.